# Proxmox System Crash Daily

Tags: linux-kernel, crash

I keep having a system crash in the early morning. Between 00:00 and 08:00.

Looking at the logs it looks like each core slows to a crawl and eventually crashes until the whole system freezes. Its about 25 Minuets from the first error to the system crash. The errors lead me to think memory issues but I am not sure if thats just because of some other failure.

The system is a Super Micro X9DRW-IF with Dual E5-2630 V2 and 16X 8GB DDR3

OS is Proxmox Latest

Kernel:
`Linux pve1 4.15.18-10-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-32 (Sat, 19 Jan 2019)`

The PERF Interrupts start taking longer and longer and memory errors start happening. Approximately 20 of these errors come up before the system freezes over a period of 20 minuets to an hour. 
As I understand the PERF is just the CPU throttling. It throttles to the lowest possible speed, at that point the system crawls.

```
Apr 28 07:36:05 pve1 kernel: [36497.018818] perf: interrupt took too long (6737393 > 4247631), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 250
Apr 28 07:36:05 pve1 kernel: [36497.018914] {1}[Hardware Error]: Hardware error from APEI Generic Hardware Error Source: 1
Apr 28 07:36:05 pve1 kernel: [36497.018926] {1}[Hardware Error]: It has been corrected by h/w and requires no further action
Apr 28 07:36:05 pve1 kernel: [36497.019012] {1}[Hardware Error]: event severity: corrected
Apr 28 07:36:05 pve1 kernel: [36497.019112] {1}[Hardware Error]:  Error 0, type: corrected
Apr 28 07:36:05 pve1 kernel: [36497.019115] {1}[Hardware Error]:  fru_text: CorrectedErr
Apr 28 07:36:05 pve1 kernel: [36497.019119] {1}[Hardware Error]:   section_type: memory error
Apr 28 07:36:05 pve1 kernel: [36497.019125] {1}[Hardware Error]:   node: 1 device: 0 
Apr 28 07:36:05 pve1 kernel: [36497.019128] {1}[Hardware Error]:   error_type: 2, single-bit ECC
Apr 28 07:36:05 pve1 kernel: [36497.019297] ghes_edac: Internal error: Can't find EDAC structure
Apr 28 07:36:06 pve1 pve-firewall[2311]: firewall update time (13.994 seconds)
Apr 28 07:36:10 pve1 kernel: [36502.054892] INFO: NMI handler (perf_event_nmi_handler) took too long to run: 451.489 msecs
Apr 28 07:36:17 pve1 pve-firewall[2311]: firewall update time (9.985 seconds)
Apr 28 07:36:20 pve1 pvestatd[2315]: got timeout
Apr 28 07:36:26 pve1 pvestatd[2315]: status update time (33.041 seconds)
Apr 28 07:36:28 pve1 pve-firewall[2311]: firewall update time (11.073 seconds)
Apr 28 07:36:50 pve1 kernel: [36542.038771] INFO: NMI handler (perf_event_nmi_handler) took too long to run: 451.686 msecs
Apr 28 07:36:56 pve1 pve-firewall[2311]: firewall update time (27.943 seconds)
Apr 28 07:36:56 pve1 pvestatd[2315]: status update time (30.979 seconds)
Apr 28 07:37:03 pve1 pve-firewall[2311]: firewall update time (6.031 seconds)
```

https://pastebin.com/9Z0A49xR

At this point I just want to get an idea of what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Co-location Host pulled the server and reseated all the DIMMs.

This has not happened now for 3 days. It would appear that as the connection is slowed by the lack of solid connection more and more data becomes corrupt until the system crashes trying to skip bad addresses. A loose connection may have also started dropping the memory voltage causing fluctuations. The voltages stayed within range but would become eratic as this started to happen.